# Task killer script problems

Tags: vbscript

I found code to kill automatically tasks in windows 10, but the task I want to kill are: Host Service: Local System that keeps updating Windows when I'm doing something and the main problem is: It has the same name (svhost.exe) as other processes.
Any ways to pull this off? I'm still a newbie

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do While 11>10
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win64_Process")
If Process.Name = "xxx.exe" then

oShell.Run "taskkill /im xxx.exe", , True
End If
next

WScript.Sleep 60000
Loop
```

Comment: You'll need to run this script with elevated permissions. That said, this script doesn't do anything that running `taskkill` directly from the command-prompt won't do.

Comment: Use the Process ID (`pid`) to uniquely identify a process, not its executable image name.

Comment: Don't use `taskill` on `svchost.exe` to stop Windows Services - use `sc stop` instead for a graceful shutdown. If you want to stop a service from starting then set it to Disabled instead of constantly trying to kill it.

Comment: Those services cannot be Disabled and I tried many ways (windows 10 keeps blocking attempts). I keep killing them manually, but they keep comming back. The main problem is: There is too many svhost.exe and script would shut them all down

Comment: Which services in particular are you finding cannot be disabled? Only a tiny number of absolutely critical Windows services cannot be disabled.

Comment: Windows Update for sure, I already tried that and weren't able to do that. Microsoft makes hard to disable updates. I played with said process file a bit and it looks like I bricked it for now